# Rename x tick marks not numeric (POSIXct) ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, rename, xticks

I want rename the `x ticks marks` with name `localtime`at my graphic, which is  `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`

My original `localtime` is in Portuguese, and I want to rename to English

Dez = December

Jan = January

Fev = February

Mar = March

ps: I can't make an real example to have the similar result of plot because have more than 2000 localtimes.

```
dt = data.table(localtime= as.POSIXct(c("2016-10-24 12:45:06", "2016-10-24 12:46:13", "2016-10-24 12:47:02", "2016-10-24 12:48:27", "2016-10-24 12:52:39", "2016-10-24 12:55:11", "2016-10-30 21:08:02", "2016-10-30 21:18:27", "2016-10-30 21:30:13","2016-10-24 23:27:21", "2016-10-26 06:54:29")),
depth_range = c("shallow", "deep"),
dmean = c(30, 50, 200, 76, 467, 87, 98, 10, 240, 176, 89))

ggplot(dt, aes( x=localtime, xend= localtime, y=0, yend= dmean, color=depth_range))+
  geom_segment( size=1)+
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Dive category", values = c("grey70", "orangered3")) +
  scale_y_reverse()+
  xlab("Time")+
  ylab ("Dive depth (m)")+
  ggtitle("Whale ID 172001_17")+
  theme_bw()
```

The real plot of my data

[image]

And I tried somethings:

```
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Dez"="December","Jan"="January", "Fev"="February", "Mar"= "March"))

scale_x_discrete(labels = c("December", "January", "February", "March"))

scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("Dez", "Jan", "Fev", "Mar"),
          labels=c("December", "January", "February", "March"))

scale_x_continuous(breaks=c("Dez", "Jan", "Fev", "Mar"),
                 labels=c("December", "January", "February", "March"))  

scale_x_continuous (names= c("December", "January", "February", "March"))

leg2<- c("December", "January", "February", "March")
scale_x_continuous(labels = leg2)

leg2<- c("December", "January", "February", "March")
scale_x_discrete(labels= leg2)

theme(axis.text.x = c("December", "January", "February", "March"))

theme(axis.text.x = element_text("December", "January", "February", "March"))

#I tried too to convert localtime to factor, but the plot didn't work well
ggplot(dt, aes( x=factor(localtime), xend= factor(localtime), y=0, yend= dmean, color=depth_range))+
```

Shows that error:

> Erro: `mapped_discrete` objects can only be created from numeric vectors

How can I fix this??

Comment: Try `+ scale_x_datetime(date_labels="%b")`, it'll label every tick with just the short month abbreviation. This will repeat month labels when the x span is short (as in this example), so other options to `scale_x_datetime` allow you to specify where to place the ticks (`breaks=` or `date_breaks=`).

Comment: but the problem is because my original data is in Portuguese, and I want to rename to English. I edited the post

Comment: One of: (1) use `scale_x_datetime(breaks=..., labels=...)`; or (2) look at `Sys.getlocale()` (in order to save the current value), then `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")` and try the plot. (Then you may want to set it back to what it was before.) I've seen others suggest `Sys.setenv(LANG="English")`, not sure if it will affect this.

Comment: the (1) and (3) didn't rename... the (2) shows: `Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale ("LC_ALL", "English"):
   SO informs that the request to define the locale as 'English' cannot be honored`

Comment: Try `Sys.setlocale(locale="English_United States.1252")` (gathered from my answer).

Answer (score 1):

I'm already in English, so I'll demonstrate by plotting into Portugeuse :-)

First, I'll save my current locale, because I don't speak Portuguese and sometimes R's errors can be confusing enough in my own language:

```r
Sys.getlocale()
# [1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
Sys.setlocale(locale="Portuguese")
# [1] "LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252"
```

Now, I plot, adding `scale_x_datetime`:

```r
ggplot(dt, aes( x=localtime, xend= localtime, y=0, yend= dmean, color=depth_range))+
  geom_segment( size=1)+
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Dive category", values = c("grey70", "orangered3")) +
  scale_y_reverse()+
  xlab("Time")+
  ylab ("Dive depth (m)")+
  ggtitle("Whale ID 172001_17")+
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%b %d")
```

I included `"%d"` because your sample data only spanned a few days; you should be able to use just `"%b"` (determined by `?strptime`).

**Note**: this highlights one possibly flaw: `ggplot2` doesn't know that the labelling format `"%b"` is no more resolute than "1 month", so if I don't include `%d` (day of month) in the format, `ggplot2` will happily show `out   out   out` on the x-axis. In your real data, this might not be a problem. You can play with other options such as `date_breaks="1 month"` to make sure that the x axis ticks are no more frequent than 1 month ... but using that here results in no ticks, since I believe it is defaulting to the first of the month and this sample has nothing on that date. You may need to hard-code `breaks=` in your scale call in order to fix where they go, and/or use a function for breaks to control where the breaks go.

[image: plot with Portuguese months]

Comment: thank you, this code run well, but didn't rename :/. Here is `Sys.getlocale()
[1] "pt_BR.UTF-8/pt_BR.UTF-8/pt_BR.UTF-8/C/pt_BR.UTF-8/pt_BR.UTF-8"`

Comment: What happened when you tried `Sys.setlocale(locale="English_United States.1252")` before the plotting code?

Comment: just doesnt  rename the ticks

Comment: I don't know what to say. On my system, I show English, change the locale, then show Portuguese, so the premise is solid, perhaps something else with your data?

Comment: What about just `Sys.setlocale(locale="English")`? The two are synonymous on my (windows) system, perhaps they're different-enough for you?